# School assignment for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop

```
int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i < 5) continue;
        if (i > 7) break;
        cout << "aaaa" << endl;
    }
```

The question is how many prints will there be. So the right answer is 3 but i don't understand why, can someone explain?
i know what is a for loop and how it works but the continue and break part i don't understand

Comment: You need to understand what `continue`, `break` and `>` and `<` meann. Step through the loop with pencil and paper.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_break_statement.htm http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_continue_statement.htm

Answer (score 0):

Only when i is 5, 6 and 7 is cout reached.
For 0 to 4 the loop "continues" - goes back to its per loop "i++" and test.
When it's 8, the loop breaks - finito.

Comment: so loop skips the first 4 lap's and it doesn't print, then when i is 5 6 7 it prints because i has to be greater than 7 to break the loop? Did i understood good?

Answer (score 0):

Continue key word breaks the iteration of the loop and move on the next iteration. And Break key word, brings you out of the loop.
So it will go like following:

when i will be 0 then loop will go again 
when i will be 1 then loop will go again 
when i will be 2 then loop will go again 
when i will be 3 then loop will go again 
when i will be 4 then loop will go again

when i will be 5 then "aaaa" 
when i will be 6 then "aaaa" 
when i will be 7 then "aaaa"

when i will be 8 then loop will end

Answer (score 0):

Until `i=5` condition `i<5` is satisfied and `continue` will be executed which jumps to the next iteration.

Then for `i=5, i=6 ,i=7` your cout statement will be executed. When it hits `i=8` break condition is satisfied and it will leave the loop.

Simply `break` will leave the loop, `continue` will jump to next iteration.